How is motor electrical power typically measured in a VFD?
In a typical VFD which employs FOC control to drive a brushless DC motor, how is electrical power generally calculated?
I ask this question because the voltage at the motor terminals is generally a 'pulsed DC' modulated over a range. The phase current can be easily seen by a current probe on an oscilloscope.
As the voltage is not constant, is it still possible to calculate power as sqrt(3) * V * I * cos(phi), assuming a balanced system?

You are indeed not able to use generic formulas like sqrt(3) * V * I * cos(phi) based on the RMS values for the power in this case.
But you can use a DSP function to calculate the instantaneous power.
By multiplying the current and voltage waveform in the time domain you will get a power waveform you can calculate an average on.
With a sufficient sample rate this will result in an accurate measurement regardless of crest factor.
When calculating power this way you can also obtain reactive power and apparent power.
Those can be used to approximate the cos(phi) again to populate your formula.
